# Верно ли управление "полмиллиона рублей штрафов"

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Феодосийские стихийщики получили полмиллиона рублей штрафов.

Answer (score 1):

*Полмиллиона рублей штрафов* - в разговорной речи я бы пропустил. Общелитературный вариант - **"штрафов на полмиллиона рублей"**.

Что совершенно невозможно - "получить штрафы".
На что заменить - не знаю. Если только на "вчинить".
*"Стихийщикам вчинены штрафы на полмиллиона рублей"* - это корректно, но слишком официально.

А, знаю!
***На стихийщиков наложены штрафы на полмиллиона.***

Answer (score 0):

1) **Обратим внимание на неправильное употребление глагола "получили**"

Возможно, феодосийские стихийщики **уплатили** полмиллиона рублей **штрафов**. А если еще не уплатили, то уплатят или не уплатят позже.  Самое главное ―  это то, что они их **не получат**. В связи с отсутствием достоверной информации  остановимся на таком варианте: "Феодосийским стихийщикам **начислено** штрафов на полмиллиона рублей.

Продолжение текста (для понимания ситуации): Более полумиллиона рублей штрафов начислили нелегальным торговцам в Феодосии с начала текущего года.

2) **А теперь перейдем к ответу на вопрос:** Верно ли согласование “полмиллиона рублей штрафов”

Обратимся к примерам:

В прошлом году с Главмосавтотранса было взыскано 700 тысяч рублей **штрафов**.В 1965 году мы уплатили 148 тысяч рублей **штрафов** за то, что опаздывали с отправкой товаров. Гостю без миграционной карты придется заплатить 500 рублей **штрафа** за административное правонарушение.

Итак, выбор варианта  **штрафа/штрафов** связан, по-видимому,  с единовременной выплатой или суммарным штрафом за какой-то период.

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что они их уплатили?!